# FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage() is not called in terminated state

Tags: flutter

FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage() is not called in terminated state when we click notification that contains message data like this ,instead it is displaying screen from splash screen

{
"registration_ids": [
""

```
],


"data": {
    "title": "Flutter9 Object Notification.3...",
    "body": "this is flutter Data Object notification test message from",
    "android_channel_id": "dgdgsdfgs",
},
"android":{
    "priority":"high"
}
```

}

Comment: I have same issue. Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

With `FCM`, you can send two types of messages to clients:

- Notification messages, are sometimes thought of as "display messages." These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.
- Data messages, which are handled by the client app. "

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

What you are trying to send is a data message, my best guess is that the firebase SDK does not recognize the data message so it does not trigger the firebase message event listener. Your notification must have a 'notification' field for firebase SDK to listen to.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **data key** only to use FCM. So, this methods not works because this only triggered with **notification key**:

1. FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()

   If the application has been opened from a terminated state via a [RemoteMessage] (containing a [**NOTIFICATION KEY**]), it will be returned, otherwise it will be null
2. FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp()

   Returns a [Stream] that is called when a user presses a notification message displayed via FCM. This method never be called if you use **data key**

So, if you use **data key** fcm, you only can trigger this method:

1. FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage()
2. FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message){...}

Answer (score -1):

Given that you not displayed how you setup your fcm , here is how to go about it

```
/// Create a [AndroidNotificationChannel] for heads up notifications
late AndroidNotificationChannel channel;

/// Initialize the [FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin] package.
late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

/// To verify things are working, check out the native platform logs.
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}
```

in main.dart

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);


// setup displaying notifications 

channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel', // id
      'High Importance Notifications', // title// description
      importance: Importance.high,
    );

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    /// Create an Android Notification Channel.
    ///
    /// We use this channel in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to override the
    /// default FCM channel to enable heads up notifications.
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
    /// heads up notifications.
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
```

handle message  call this in your initstate

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage? message) {
      if (message != null) {
        // do message things
      }
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      showMessage(message: message);
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;

      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
                android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                  channel.id,
                  channel.name,
                ),
                iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(subtitle: notification.title)));
      }
    });
```

incase you need to navigate on receiving a message

```
void showMessage({required RemoteMessage message}) async {
    if (message.data['route'] == "mypage") {
      var myparams =  message.data['payload'];
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          fullscreenDialog: true,
          builder: (_) {
            return MyPage(
             params:myparams,
            );
          })); ...
```

Comment: yes, but FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage() is not triggering when we clicked on that notification since i am displaying it as local notification

Comment: is the app in foreground or background?

Comment: completely terminated or closed

Comment: Still facing this issue. Any update @Saikiran